# Issues clearing cells in Excel Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

The following code is suppose to clear the value of the cells from A15:H in Excel:

```
'Set TargetSheet and clear the previous contents
targetSheet = "Lägg in Ärende"
tRow = 15
lastRow = Sheets(targetSheet).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets(targetSheet).Range("A15:H" & lastRow).ClearContents
```

It works correctly when there is existing values in cells A15:H.

But when the cells are empty in A15:H and you still run the macro then all the cells in **A2, A9 and A14:H14** gets erased. Does anybody have an idea why?

Comment: What "entire worksheet gets erased" mean?
If you have column A empty, macro will erase all value from range A1:H15 .

Comment: I have texts written in cells: **A2**, **A9** and **A14:H14**. These gets erased also, which I dont want them to.

Comment: ...which is not the *entire* sheet as your question implied. :) Please be more descriptive with your questions in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will help you.

```
targetSheet = "Lägg in Ärende"
lastRow = Sheets(targetSheet).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

IF lastRow<15 THEN lastRow=15
Sheets(targetSheet).Range("A15:H" & lastRow).ClearContents
```

Comment: Wonderful, it did the job, thank you. Could you briefly explain what you did?

Comment: Empty column A will set lastRow value equals 1. In `Sheets(targetSheet).Range("A15:H" & lastRow).ClearContents` you have hard code range "A15:H"& lastRow variable. So when lastRow=1 that Range will looks like "A1:H15".

In your previous code try add `MsgBox(Sheets(targetSheet).Range("A15:H" & lastRow).Address)` to clearly understand this logic :)

Sorry about my English :)